# Clickpad: how to right-click with both Two-Fingers and Area

Tags: touchpad, 18.04, gnome-tweak-tool

I've got a buttonless touchpad, so-called clickpad, and I want to be able to perform a right click by both tapping with two fingers and clicking in the right-bottom area. The `gnome-tweak-tool` allows me to change between these two behaviors but doesn't have the option to turn them on both at the same time.

I mostly use the two-finger tap for right-click, but in some applications I need to click-and-drag with the right or middle button. However the usual tap-tap-hold to emulate holding the mouse button only works with one finger, so it's not possible to use it to emulate holding of the right button.

I'm using Ubuntu 18.04 on XOrg.

Answer (score 9):

I was able to achieve this by using the `gnome-tweak-tool` and enabling the `area` Mouse click emulation under the Keyboard & Mouse section.

Then I added a new file in `/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d` and named it `90-libinput-quirks.conf` with the following content

```
Section "InputClass"
        Identifier "libinput touchpad catchall"
        MatchIsTouchpad "on"
        MatchDevicePath "/dev/input/event*"
        Driver "libinput"
        Option "Tapping" "True"
EndSection
```

The file name itself is somewhat important, it needs to start with a higher number than the libinput.conf file bundled with Ubuntu 18.04. Mine was named `40-libinput.conf` so I named mine `90-libinput-quirks.conf` to make sure it was loaded after, and thus overriding, the original config.

Alternatively you could just add the `Option "Tapping" "True"` to the section identifier `Identifier "libinput touchpad catchall"` just as above. Not sure if this file could be overwritten by something like an update, so I prefer the first approach.

Answer (score 1):

On some systems, enabling "Area" under GNOME Tweaks (Keyboard & Mouse) actually enables both finger and area click emulation.

Source: https://itsfoss.com/fix-right-click-touchpad-ubuntu/