# Right click does not work even after using Gnome Tweaks

Tags: drivers, gnome, 18.04, touchpad, gnome-tweak-tool

Ubuntu 18.04.1 64 bit

I have a touchpad that is split at the bottom for right and left clicks. The sides are not separate buttons. When I boot Windows, depressing the bottom-right corner produces that standard right-click effect: a menu appears. Like others, I found that this feature had been turned off with Ubuntu 18.04, but, unlike others, **I have been unable to turn it back on**.

I **installed Gnome Tweaks and set "mouse click emulation" to "area"**. This made the two-finger tap gesture stop working but did not make clicking the lower right bring up a menu. Tapping the bottom right corner works the same as a tap anywhere else on the touchpad, but depressing the bottom right corner to where it clicks produces no effect.

**Synaptics does not seem to be in use**. `xinput list` gives

```
⎡ Virtual core pointer                id=2  [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer      id=4  [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ ETPS/2 Elantech Touchpad        id=12 [slave  pointer  (2)]
```

`xinput list-props 12` gives a bunch of libinput rules but does not mention Synaptics (why I think it is not being used). This way of determining the touchpad driver came from [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1049965/how-do-i-found-out-which-touchpad-driver-is-being-usedhttp://). When I look at "Additional Drivers" in "Software & Updates", I see "**No proprietary drivers are in use**".

However, when I look in `/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d`, there are two Synaptics files. I tried renaming these files so that their numbers were lower than the libinput numbers so that I now have the files

```
50-synaptics.conf
51-synaptics-quirks.conf
90-libinput.conf
91-libinput-quirks.conf
```

Would deleting these Synaptics files or uninstalling Synaptics help? What else could be causing this?

Note that `91-libinput-quirks.conf` contains code taken from [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1041592/clickpad-how-to-right-click-with-both-two-fingers-and-area) to make the two-finger tap work even when Tweaks has the input set to "area" (but the Tweaks setting did not work even before I created this file, so this cannot be the reason it does not work). Note also that some people have been reporting that setting "mouse click emulation" to "area" allows for *both* two-finger tap and bottom-right click while other people are reporting that they can only toggle between the two, so I am not sure whether this file is even supposed to be needed, but that is likely a separate issue.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, I just installed Gnome Tweaks and set mouse click emulation to area. Then multiple times clicked on the bottom right area with various places that worked for me.